# Execute PgSQL with perl-DBI?

Tags: perl, postgresql, plpgsql, dbi

I need to execute complex SQLs at PostgreSQL server .

Something like this:

```
$sql=<<EOF;
BEGIN;
DO SOME SQL HERE
END;
EOF

$dbh->do($sql) ;
```

If this is not possible, how can I create and execute stored procedure in DBD::Pg?
I have no access to additional software or libraries but perl + DBI

Where is the manuals about how to work with PGSQL by  perl-DBI ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a very possible to execute a complex SQL and stored procedures from a Perl program. See e.g.

- [DBI site](http://dbi.perl.org/)
- [DBI module documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm)
- [DBI::do](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#do)
- [How can I invoke stored procedures with DBI?](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/ADESC/DBI-FAQ-0.38/FAQ.pm#5.3-How-can-I-invoke-stored-procedures-with-DBI?)

With PostgreSQL the stored procedure execution example from DBI FAQ is:

```
$dbh->do( "SELECT someProcedure;" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the DBD::Pg driver; You can find it at cpan:
https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Pg